# Bind height of BoxView or Frame to (hidden) NavigationBar in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, navigationbar, custom-view

Instead of having the standard NavigationBar on the mainpage, I want to hide that one and load a custom one. I think using a <s>BoxView</s> (**edit**:) frame is the best method for this. However, How do I bind the height(request) of a BoxView to a (hidden) NavigationBar, preferably in Xaml?

(*frame of boxview should have the same method*)

Comment: If you use a custom control the funny part is that you don't need system height at all as you can use your own. Say you need 50 instead of 47. So set it manually. The other different point is that you need to know the height of the StatusBar AND page insets in case of a frameless ios device or ios top calling or modem sharing bar.

Answer (score 0):

For two common controls, you can bind a height of one control to another control like this(take BoxView and a Button as an example):

```
<BoxView Color="Yellow"
         x:Name="testbox"
         WidthRequest="160"
         HeightRequest="60"
         VerticalOptions="Center"
         HorizontalOptions="Center" />

<Button Text="test..." 
        BindingContext="{x:Reference testbox}"
        WidthRequest="160"
        HeightRequest="{Binding Path=HeightRequest}"/>
```

**Update**

You can get the NavigationBar height on each platform using custom renderer.
And Then binding the height of NavigationBar to Boxview by following the method above.

**For Android:**

```
public class NaviRendererForAndroid : NavigationPageRenderer
{
public CustomNaviForAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
{

}
protected override void 
OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    var height = 0;

    Resources resources = Context.Resources;
    int resourceId = resources.GetIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0)
    {
        height = resources.GetDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
  }
}
```

**For IOS:**

```
public class NaviRendererForiOS : NavigationRenderer
{
  protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    var height = NavigationBar.Bounds.Height;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey there, I think we misunderstood each other. I want to have the BoxView element to have the same height as the navigationbar to make a custom one. I want to edit the height of the BoxView (or frame), not the navigation bar.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can check it.Hope it can help you.